# Docker container ports are clashing in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am deploying docker containers on a kubernetes cluster with 2 nodes. The docker containers need to have port 50052 open. My understanding was that I just need to define a containerPort (50052) and have a service that points to this.

But when I deploy this, only the first 2 pods will spin up successfully. After that, I get the following message, presumably because the new pods are trying top open port 50052, which is already being used.

> 0/2 nodes are available: 2 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.

I thought that multiple pods with the same requested port could be scheduled on the same node? Or is this not right?

Comment: Can you add your Deployment YAML file(s) to the question to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @DavidMaze I figured it out -- I had the host network flag set to true in my yaml which is what caused this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, I figured it out -- I had set host network to true in my kubernetes deployment. Changing this back to false fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, multiple pods with the same port can exist in a cluster. They have to have the type: ClusterIP

ClusterIP: Exposes the Service on a cluster-internal IP. Choosing this value makes the Service only reachable from within the cluster. This is the default ServiceType.

To avoid port clashes you should not use NodePort as port type. Because if you have 2 nodes and 4 pods, more then one pod will exist on each node causing a port clash.

Depending on how you want to reach your cluster, you have then different options...